# NHibernate 2 FKs to same PK in one-to-one relationship

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a one-to-one relationship between an Envelope and a Transaction. I mapped it using a primary key association as below:

```
<class name="Envelope" table="T_ENVELOPE">
    <id name="EnvelopeId" column="ENVELOPE_ID"><generator class="identity"/></id>
    <one-to-one class="Transaction" cascade="all" name="Transaction" />
</class>
<class name="Transaction" table="T_TRANSACTION">
    <id name="TransactionID" column="TRANSACTION_ID" type="long"><generator class="foreign"><param name="property">Envelope</param></generator></id>
    <one-to-one name="Envelope" class="Envelope" constrained="true" />
</class>
```

This works fine, but my case is complicated since `T_TRANSACTION` has 2 FKs that both map to `T_ENVELOPE's PK (ENVELOPE_ID): TRANSACTION_ID` (as shown above) and `OLD_DEPRECATED_TXN_ID`. So, I have 2 FKs in `T_ENVELOPE` that have the exact same value (the envelope's id). How can I make NHibernate save `ENVELOPE_ID` not just in `TRANSACTION_ID` but also in `OLD_DEPRECATED_TXN_ID` as well?

I wish I didn't have this requirement, but I'm dealing with legacy code schemas and code. I know I can also do something like:

1. envelope.Save // this saves Envelope and Transaction's transaction ID but not OLD_DEPRECATED_TXN_ID
2. envelope.transaction.old_deprecated_txn_id = envelope.id
3. envelope.Save
   But, that results in one insert and one update. How do I do a one insert only?

Here's an example:

```
T_ENVELOPE
----------
ENVELOPE_ID
1
9
121

T_TRANSACTION
-------------
TRANSACTION_ID | OLD_DEPRECATED_TXN_ID
1|1
9|9
121|121
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.. can you make the two tables - Transaction and Envelope and show their columns under them and then tell us what is the expected association between them?

Comment: I apologize my question isn't clear. It's actually an extremely simple setup: you have one table with 2 foreign keys pointing to the same primary key of another table. I hope my example explains things better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your requirements you could:

1. Write a stored procedure to perform the insert and configure NHibernate to use this procedure in the mappings. I have taken this approach when working with legacy DBs and historic fields that were not being used but had to be populated
2. Use an [Interceptor](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#manipulatingdata-interceptors). Something along the followings lines should work. Not tested though!

   ```
   public class TransactionEntityInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
   {


     public override boolean OnSave(object entity,
                     object id,
                     object[] state,
                     string[] propertyNames,
                     IType[] types)
     {
         if (entity is Transaction)
         {
             Object TransactionID;
             for ( int i=0; i<propertyNames.Length; i++ )
             {
                 if ( "TransactionID" == propertyNames[i] )
                 {
                     TransactionID = state[i];
                     return true
                 }
             }

             for ( int i=0; i<propertyNames.Length; i++ )
             {
                 if ( "OLD_DEPRECATED_TXN_ID" == propertyNames[i] )
                 {
                     state[i] = TransactionID;
                     return true;
                 }
             }
             return false;
         }
         else
         {
             return true;
         }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I was hoping there is a more "automatic" way. Thanks.